# Floating point numbers multiplication in verilog

Tags: floating-point, verilog, multiplication

I want to get the 16-bit data for floating point multiplication but the resutls was wrong and not what I demanded.By the way is the real must be in 64 pin?

```
module calc(input [15:0]a, b,
            output [15:0]o);

assign o = a * b;

endmodule
```

here is the testbench:

```
module calc_tb();

real a,b,o;

calc U1 (.a(a),.b(b),.o(o));
initial begin
a <= 2.2;
b <= 2.5;
#2;
a <= -4.8;
b <= 2.9;
#2;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Which 16 bits do you want? You are starting, as @Morgan pointed out, with naturally 64 bit data. There are many, many different functions that map from 64 bits to 16 bits, so you need to specify which you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run this you should be getting warnings along the lines of:

```
Port size (16 or 16) does not match connection size (64) 
  for port 'a'. The port definition is at: calc.sv(2).
```

For`a`,`b` and `o`, as you have defined them as 16 bits and reals are 64 bits.

Just changing the port to 64 bits will make verilog think your passing in a 64 bit integer. You need to make the ports of type real:

```
module calc(
  input  real a,
  input  real b,
  output real o
);

assign o = a * b;

endmodule
```

Note that this is not synthesisable. Synthesisable Verilog can not handle floating point out of the box. You need to implement or import a floating point core.

Comment: Any idea on changing the 64 pin to 16 pin? And also how to implement or import floating point core? I done some simply research but still not very understand on how it works to load the core on to modelsim.

Comment: @Jack93 What is wrong with real/why 16 bits? What do you want the 16 bits to be? Do you want fractional rather than floating point?

Comment: Sorry about that @Morgan, guess I mix it up with fix point arithmetic which only needing 16 bits. I would like the data to be in 16 bits. How should i able to do that?